# C- reading the second line of a file gets to bug on mac gnu gcc

Tags: c, string, file, scanf

Ive made the following code on xcode, which is supposed to read the second line of the following contained in a .txt file:

paraedicao \n olá mundo \n
hello world

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file; char x[140];
    file=fopen("/Users/pedrosecchi/Desktop/Projetos/LABCES-10/paraedicao.txt", "r+");
    fscanf(file, "\n%s\n", x);
    printf("%s", x);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

after compiling and running the output was this:
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200

what is that supposed to mean? what is wrong with the code?
Your help is appreciated!!

Comment: Looks like paraedicao.txt is an RTF file. Have you tried a different file?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage lemme try again with a .txt extension....

Comment: Try creating the file using the same editor that you used to write your C source code.

Comment: it worked!! can i program the mac textedit app to always save files as raw text?

Comment: Well, ... yes. But there are better text editors available for programmers. Try [Atom](https://atom.io/) or [TextWrangler](https://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).